# Having trouble fetching from an api not sure what I am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch from an api to and display the data im getting. I have tried using regular fetch with promises and axios and it doesnt seem to be doing anything. Im using the .map() method and I am getting the error map is not a function.

I have tried using fetch and axios to try and get the data from the api.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';



    class RecentNews extends Component {
        state = {
          recentArticles: [],
          recentReports: [],
          isLoaded: false,
        }


    componentDidMount(){
      fetch(`https://spaceflightnewsapi.net/api/v1/articles?page=1`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => this.setState(
            { recentArticles: json,
              isLoaded: true,
            }
          ))
    }


    render(){

      let { recentArticles, isLoaded } = this.state

      if (!isLoaded) {
        return <h1>Loading.....</h1>
          }

      else {

      return(
        <div className="recentnews">
        <div>
        { recentArticles.map(articles =>
          <p>{articles.title}</p>
        )


        }
        </div>

            </div>

          )
        }
      }
    }


    export default RecentNews
```

here is the error I'm getting

> TypeError: recentArticles.map is not a function
>
> ▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: check response structure - not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` is a function of Arrays in JavaScript - that API is returning an Object.

It would appear that what you want is the `docs` array inside that object, so try changing that line to:

```
{ recentArticles.docs.map(articles =>
```

The other keys in the object that is returned by that API relate to the pagination. You should use those to create pagination controls, for example, next page, previous page links etc.